# SQL Server "Locate backup file" change to include diff

Tags: sql-server, ssms

In SSMS, when using the GUI to select backup files to restore, the .diff are excluded (First image) and you need to change to show all files (second image).

.diff is the file extension I am using for differential backups. Extension types for SQL backups beyond the 3 primary are fairly open, someone might choose other extensions for any number of reasons. Other then not being visible in the GUI as pictured, I am not aware of any other issues with varied extension types.

I have googled around and not found anything about this.

I have looked through all the tools > Options choices, and not found a place to add '.diff' to the backup file types to display.

I am using SSMS v18.2

How can I change the values in "Locate backup file" to include other extensions?

[image: Not showing diff]
[image: Showing diff]

Comment: That might be a GUI limitation. You should use tsql which does not care what your file extensions are.

Comment: [sp_DatabaseRestore](https://github.com/BrentOzarULTD/SQL-Server-First-Responder-Kit/blob/master/sp_DatabaseRestore.sql) is a good place to start. There's always [dbatools](https://dbatools.io/) if you prefer powers hell.

Comment: ...or just change the extension on your diffs to ".diff.bak"